# right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with funct result sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

```
fun can_move    0 0 0 nil = false
|   can_move    limit_down V 0 a  = true
|   can_move    limit_down V count a =  if  ((V-limit_down)>hd a) then false else               can_move limit_down V (count-1) tl a ;
```

Hey this my code I just want to check if the value V-limit_down is lower  that the numbers in the int list a.The number of arguments i want to check from the a list are V/10 . For example if i have 20 V then i want to check the first two arguments of the list. Why do i get this error?

```
can_move.sml:1.6-3.114 Error:right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function     result type
[tycon mismatch] 
expression: int -> int -> int list -> bool
result type: int -> int -> (Z' list -> 'Z list) -> int list -> bool
in declaration:

can_move (fn arg =) (fn <pat> => <exp>))
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you forgot parentheses in the last right-hand side of your pattern match. In the recursive call `can_move limit_down V (count-1) tl a`, notice that your last argument is `tl a`. Normally, the parser can figure out that this is a function application. Unfortunately, it's ambiguous when the result of the application is part of yet another application, as it is here.

The solution is to parenthesize the call: `can_move limit_down V (count-1) (tl a)`.

Comment: Not that stupid. I could not figure out the parenthesis miss, thanks to your question i solved it now. @MikEKOU